react-native-google-places API not working inside a <Modal>
my API working fine in my screen page, but I would like to work it inside a 
No idea why inside a modal appear just the text input without the placeholder, we can type something but the autocomplete dropdown does not appear
images inside and


inside and outside, I tried put inside scroll view, tried manipulate styles with zindex and elevation, height everything

Jesus, i think this was the faster post answer I could get,
Inside the modal it requests the native style property "container: { }" and then I passed position absolute, zero top, left, right, and override zIndex and elevation, and it worked inside the modal
for anyone who is experiencing that, solved here
...

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
